# How to achieve CSS class-like styling of buttons in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-material

I am new to flutter, and I want to reduce code duplication when it comes to UI.

Let's say that I chose some theme. `ElevatedButton` will have color of that theme.

Now, I want to have some buttons that will by styled alternatively (e.g. 'Cancel' buttons to be grey or 'Accept' buttons to be bright green).

Normally I do like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.grey[100]),
  onPressed: () {
    // onPressed logic here
  },
  child: const Text(
    'Cancel',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
  ),
),
```

but if I have multiple Cancel buttons, this code would be repeated:
`style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.grey[100]),` and
`style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),`

What is "Flutter" way to achieve it so I can have "Cancel" or "Accepted" style defined in one place? Should I create my own widget `CancelButton`? or is there better way?

Answer (score 0):

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: Styles.cancelButtonStyle(),
  onPressed: () {
    // onPressed logic here
  },
  child: const Text(
    'Cancel',
    style: Styles.cancelButtonTextStyle(),
  ),
),
```

Your Custom Style Class

```
class Styles{

  static TextStyle cancelButtonTextStyle(){
   return TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16,
      color: Colors.black54
    );
  }

 static TextStyle acceptButtonTextStyle(){
   return TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16,
      color: Colors.black54
    );
  }

 static ButtonStyle cancelButtonStyle(){
   return ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.grey[100]);
 }
 static ButtonStyle acceptButtonStyle(){
   return ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.green[700]);
 }
}
```